# How can i make a script to navigate in apps and press buttons, log in... c# .net framework

Tags: c#, .net

I'm fairly new to programming and i want to learn how i can make an application to open and navigate in another app (press buttons, typing and more).

Example:

1. I opened the Photos app and looks like this: [photos app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItmNO.png)
2. Now i want to send a command to the Photos app and click import for example [click import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn7Fp.png)

Now the question is how i can do that? I can get somehow the button address or something like that and send an input? For example with button address i'm referring at something like static addresses you find it in Cheat Engine for games to change health and more.

I know a method to make this script with image search (find the icon, get coordinate and press) but this is not what i want, i want something 100% safe is pressed that button.

I don't know if i was explicit or not, if you think i'm not please ask me more!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the original primary purpose of AutoHotkey, a FOSS Windows scripting language.  This particular task is easy to do with it, and you can start by reading the documentation for the Click command, which is here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm

For example, if you wanted to Shift+click a particular point on your screen at {x,y} coordinates {100,200}, you could use this line of code in an AutoHotkey script:

```
Send +{Click 100 200}  ; Shift+LeftClick
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it's not what i need. I want something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5VyzlBf400&ab_channel=AyoubBourhet

I really don't know if this is possible /// I don't want to send click on specific coords because in some cases, the user have different pixels amount... ex: 1080p and 720p, it's not the same